# Acer Bios Blink codes

Tags: power, acer-aspire

I have an Acer 5735 that won't turn on, when I press the power button I get 5 blinks of the battery light. I'm wondering if someone has a chart or guide for how many blinks mean what.

I've tried re-seating everything in the machine (currently apart).

Comment: "My ship works better when I kick it"

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a 5735 right now. On the very rare occasions (2 I think) that it has failed to boot, I removed the battery and power cord, held down the power button for about a minute, let go and then reinserted the battery & power then pressed the power button.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I just tested the AC adapter and it was bad, replaced it with a universal, now it appears to be charging but won't boot. I'm going to try holding the power button and see if that will do anything